# BoxSDK Python OAuth2 invalid_client

Tags: python, box

I'm facing a lot of difficulty trying to authenticate my app for OAuth2 using python. When I try to authenticate I run into a problem of invalid_client. Could you please help me resolve it?

The following is my (relevant) code:

```
def setupOAuth2(cid):
    oauth = OAuth2(client_id=BOX['APP_KEY'],
                   client_secret=BOX['APP_SECRET'],
                   store_tokens=store_token)
    auth_url, csrf_token = oauth.get_authorization_url(u'https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize')
    print '1. Go to: ' + auth_url + ' and login.'
    print '2. Click "Grant" (you might have to log in first)'
    print '3. Copy the authorization code.'
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)
    code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()
    oauth.authenticate(code)
```

I end up getting to the auth page where I log in, then click grant. After I click grant I get the error page:

[image]

P.S. The error details are as follows:

```
 Show Error Details
state=box_csrf_token_fyMyuQcEAKqtAeEf
```